# Multiple Graphs on one page

Tags: javascript, chart.js, radar-chart

I have a website displaying inplay stats from football matches, I have a large number of stats and want to try and get away from just line after line of numbers in a table. Im using jquery datatables and have added a drop down for each row of data with more stats. In this drop down I would like a canvas.js radar graph

The problem is I cant find a way round having to initialise each chart with lots of code and that code would then be repeated on every line of the table, as a busy time that could be over 100 matches

below is the code of what I want to achieve but I want that in every row of a datatable, ideally I would like to initialise the graphs once and just have a single line of code in my datatable with the numbers

Any ideas ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Radar Chart</title>
    <script src="dist/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="utils.js"></script>
    <style>
        canvas {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<button id="save-btn">Save Chart Image</button>
    <div style="width:40%">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        };

        var color = Chart.helpers.color;
        var config = {
            type: 'radar',
            data: {
                labels: [['Shots on', ' Target'], ['Shots Off', 'Target'], 'Corners', 'possession (out of 10)'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Home team',
                    backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    pointBackgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    data: [
                        '5',
                        '7',
                        '4',
                        '6',
                        '2'
                    ]
                }, {
                    label: 'Away Team',
                    backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    pointBackgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    data: [
                        '2',
                        '1',
                        '3',
                        '5',
                        '0'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'In Play Stats'
                },
                scale: {
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        window.onload = function() {
            window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), config);


        };






    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I could think of is creating a function, if all of your charts are similar and only few parameters change, for example in the following example I've considered `chartId`, `labels`, `dataset` and `title` to be varying. You can also aim to write function that creates datasets given certain parameters:

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
window.chartColors = {
  red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
  yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
  green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
  blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
  purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
  grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};
var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var labels = [
  ['Shots on', ' Target'],
  ['Shots Off', 'Target'], 'Corners', 'possession (out of 10)'
];
var datasets = [{
  label: 'Home team',
  backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
  borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
  pointBackgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
  data: ['5', '7', '4', '6', '2']
}, {
  label: 'Away Team',
  backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
  borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
  pointBackgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
  data: ['2', '1', '3', '5', '0']
}];

window.onload = function() {
  window.myRadar = createChart('canvas', labels, datasets, 'In Play Stats');
};

function createChart(chartId, labels, dataset, title) {
  return new Chart(document.getElementById(chartId), {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: dataset
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: title
      },
      scale: {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:40%; min-width: 700px;">
  <canvas id="canvas" style="width: 700px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks to be brilliant, exactly what I wanted , thank you

Comment: @MikeHobson glad to help :)! You can accept the answer if your issue is resolved

Comment: answer  accepted, can you tell me would it be possible to use Ajax to provide the data, so I would create the datasets, lablels and labels for each graph along with the canvas name and store as json, which wouold then be read and displayed, it would just make my solution a lot neater. Your solution works perfectly just tying to make it neater :-)

Comment: @MikeHobson yes sure, I’m afk right now, I will definitely update the answer accordingly when I reach home :D